# How to merge a single column of a list of dataframes with the same colum names into a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

So I have a list of 10 dataframes:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10]
```

All those dataframes follow the same format with the same column names:

`Date, Price, High, Low`

I'd like to create a new dataframe using `Date` and `Price` from every single one of those dataframes and change those column names to `Price1, Price2, Price3, ...` based on the dataframe it's being pulled from. The result would look like this: `Date, Price1, Price2, Price3, ... ,Price10` as columns. Is there a fancy way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. The frames are aligned on the `Date` column.

```py
result = pd.concat(
    [df.set_index("Date")["Price"].rename(f"Price{i+1}") for i, df in enumerate(dfs)],
    axis=1,
)
```

You can then reset or keep `Date` on the index.